# Inventory help Python

Tags: python, inventory, text-based

So I'm trying to arrange how the gameplay of my text base game will function if the player may/not have certain items in their inventory.

```
 print ("You are back in your cell. You saw your bed, broken sink, grotty toilet, cut up jumpsuit")
    if "comb" and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle.")
    else "comb" not in inventory and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and comb.")
    else "razor" not in inventory and "comb" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and razor")
```

it is telling me that I have a syntax error in this line of code

```
else "comb" not in inventory and "razor" in inventory:
```

I can't seem to see what mistake I have made, I am a beginner so perhaps there is an alternative way of executing my needs.

Comment: I think you mean `elif`, not `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there

The `else` works only that way

```
else:
    do something
```

So your code would be like that

```
 print ("You are back in your cell. You saw your bed, broken sink, grotty toilet, cut up jumpsuit")
    if "comb" and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle.")
    elif "comb" not in inventory and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and comb.")
    elif "razor" not in inventory and "comb" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and razor")
```

Or that

```
 print ("You are back in your cell. You saw your bed, broken sink, grotty toilet, cut up jumpsuit")
    if "comb" and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle.")
    elif "comb" not in inventory and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and comb.")
    else: #using the else here
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and razor")
```

However, when testing your code, I realized that the way you've put your logic will not work correctly.

Using that `if all(x in inventory for x in ['comb','razor'])`will treat correctly the presence of the two variables, `comb` and `razor` in `inventory` and allow the other conditions to be rolled out in a correct manner if one of the other value was missing.

```
inventory = ['comb','razor']
#inventory = ['razor','']
#inventory = ['comb']

print("You are back in your cell. You saw your bed, broken sink, grotty toilet, cut up ju
mpsuit")
if all(x in inventory for x in ['comb','razor']):
    print ("and the table with the empty bottle.")
elif ('comb' not in inventory) and ('razor' in inventory):
    print("and the table with the empty bottle and comb.")
elif ('razor' not in inventory) and ('comb' in inventory):
    print("and the table with the empty bottle and razor")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("You are back in your cell. You saw your bed, broken sink, grotty toilet, cut up jumpsuit")
    if "comb" and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle.")
    elif "comb" not in inventory and "razor" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and comb.")
    elif "razor" not in inventory and "comb" in inventory:
        print ("and the table with the empty bottle and razor")
```